Visual Studio Code: Change Style of Error Underline
Edit: Turns it it wasn't related to my screen but a bug in the latest VS Code version that will be fixed with the May version – see this PR: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/210481

On my new screen I can't really see the wavy underlines showing errors and warnings from my linter and I wondered whether it would be possible to configure a different fontWeight for these. Also they probably could use a little more spacing to the text they are underlining (see screenshot).
Any ideas?


@CPlus: The image is not here to show actual code but to show the misplacement of the squiggly error underline which makes it unreadable. There is no way to substitute this as plain text. I've added an image description though.

My mistake, sorry
